# how to get json from an application to my mule application

Tags: mule, esb

I want to link two applications with my mule application. so it must get information from the first one (msg, token), and add another information (email) and replay all this information to the second application.
this is my code:

```
<db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration" host="localhost" port="3306" user="root" database="mulesoft" doc:name="MySQL Configuration"/>
    <smtp:gmail-connector name="Gmail" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Gmail"/>
<flow name="flows1Flow1">

    <http:inbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="8084"  encoding="UTF-8" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
        <set-variable variableName="msg" value="#[message.payload.msg]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <set-variable variableName="tkn" value="#[message.payload.tkn]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select * from push where token = #[message.payload['token']]]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each">
            <set-session-variable variableName="email" value="#[message.payload.email]" doc:name="Session Variable"/>
            <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
            <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" address="http://slice.WS.com/api.php/push/send_test_push" contentType="application/json" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        </foreach>

</flow>
```

When i test with posting json information with postman (google chrome extension) i get this result:
[image]

1. What's wrong?
2. How can i recover response from the second application (Web service) which is in json format? 
   Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't build a specific response object that can properly be serialized over HTTP so Mule uses what's produced by the latest message processor of the flow as the response.

In your case, the `for-each` produces a `List` object and Mule dutifully serializes it as the HTTP response.

You need to add an `http:response-builder` element and a `set-payload` message processor to create an HTTP response that makes sense to the caller of your inbound-endpoint.

Example:

```
<set-payload value="OK"/>
<http:response-builder status="200" contentType="text/plain" />
```

Reference: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Response+Builder

Comment: I was waiting for your helpful answers. please take a look at what I did and the error that I get, i really need your help, and i have to do this test before monday. new code: http://pastebin.com/EfWcWpp5 and this is the error: http://pastebin.com/W5t4Td6W thank you for your time and please please please how can i do the second party of the test i tried a lot of things but nothing works.

Comment: But... the response builder and set payload have to be **outside** of the for-each. Re-read my answer: I told you the for-each produces a list!

Comment: Pastebin ? Otherwise how could I help?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, in the pastebin I see an HTTP outbound endpoint _after_ the response builder. Building the response should be the last thing in your flow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74483/discussion-between-rajeun-and-david-dossot).